# Google maps launch link with "Current Location" as source address

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, gps

I faced a problem with creating Google maps launch link which has to have "Current Location" string as source address.

The problem is when there is a need to generate this link and share it with someone. In this case there is a need to know what is the locale of a friend's smartphone in order to generate correct link.

For example the following link will work only on devices with English or British locale: 
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=32.026685,34.742092

Is there any universal way of creating such a link so that it would work on all devices regardless of their locale.

Comment: have you found a solution? been asking the same thing :)

Comment: Actually yes. Will post my solution soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `saddr` parameter in Google maps launch link. It has to be one of the three options:

1. A source address
2. A source location (lat,lng)
3. "Current address" - string which tells Google maps app to start from current location.

First two are no problem, but third one in most cases is being treated as an address string instead of command to take current location. It works correctly if it is in the same locale as  phone which launches the link. For example "Lieu actuel" is "Current location" in Franch and will work on devices which locale is French, but won't work on devices with any other locale(English for example)
This fact may not be a problem if you know recepient's local, but in most cases you are not.

My solution was to use help HTML page which receives destination address/point as a GET parameter and generates Google launch link with either user location pint or "Current location" string in appropriate locale as a source address/point

I'm using browser's geolocation api to retrieve location and static array of translations of "Current location" string.

This is simple visual structure of HTML help page:

[image]

This is complete HTML page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</style>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-8-i">
        <title>My Title!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getQueryVariable(variable) {
                variable = variable.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]" + variable + "=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                var results = regex.exec(document.URL);
                if (results == null)
                    return "";
                else
                    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }



            var langArr = new Array();
            langArr["nl"] = "Huidige locatie";     
            langArr["en"] = "Current Location";    
            langArr["fr"] = "Lieu actuel";         
            langArr["de"] = "Aktueller Ort";       
            langArr["it"] = "Posizione attuale";   
            langArr["ja"] = "???";
            langArr["es"] = "Ubicacion actual";
            langArr["ar"] = "?????? ??????";     
            langArr["ca"] = "Ubicacio actual";   
            langArr["cs"] = "Soucasna poloha";    
            langArr["da"] = "Aktuel lokalitet";
            langArr["el"] = "???????? ?????????";
            langArr["en-gb"] = "Current Location";
            langArr["en-us"] = "Current Location";
            langArr["fi"] = "Nykyinen sijainti";   
            langArr["he"] = "????? ?????";        
            langArr["he-il"] = "????? ?????";     
            langArr["hr"] = "Trenutna lokacija";  
            langArr["hu"] = "Jelenlegi helyszin"   
            langArr["id"] = "Lokasi Sekarang";     
            langArr["ko"] = "?? ??";             
            langArr["ms"] = "Lokasi Semasa";      
            langArr["no"] = "Nav?rende plassering";
            langArr["pl"] = "Biezace polozenie";   
            langArr["pt"] = "Localizacao Atual";    
            langArr["pt-pt"] = "Localizacao actual"; 
            langArr["ro"] = "Loc actual";           
            langArr["ru"] = "Òåêóùåå ðàçìåùåíèå";
            langArr["ru-ru"] = "Òåêóùåå ðàçìåùåíèå";
            langArr["sk"] = "Aktualna poloha";      
            langArr["sv"] = "Nuvarande plats";      
            langArr["th"] = "???????????????";     
            langArr["tr"] = "Su Anki Yer";         
            langArr["uk"] = "Ïîòî÷íå ì³ñöå";      
            langArr["vi"] = "V? tri Hi?n t?i";  
            langArr["zh-cn"] = "????";
            langArr["zh-tw"] = "????";


            var coordinate = getQueryVariable("ll");     
            var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
            language = language.toLowerCase();
            if (navigator.geolocation != undefined)
            {
                if  (coordinate != "")

                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,
                                                            errorCallback,
                                                            {maximumAge:000000});
            }

            else
            {   
                errorCallback("");
            }


            function successCallback(position) {
                if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1)  || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1))
                              window.location = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&daddr=" + coordinate;
                            else
                              window.location = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&daddr=" + coordinate;

            }



            function errorCallback(error) {
                alert("Sorry cannot determine your current location. Please select \"Current Location\" as point A in google maps");
                window.location = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + langArr[language].replace(" ","+") + "&daddr=" + coordinate;
            }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:460px; LEFT:80px; WIDTH:370px; HEIGHT:50px" >    
            Please wait.<br/>Detecting your location...<br/>If nothing happens for long time please use the following link:
            <h3><a href="javascript:errorCallback('');">Manually launch Google Maps</a></h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Some of strings could not be passed correctly and shown as questions. Use google translate to translate these.